# how to get rid of that "end of text"

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a small program in C to reverse content of input file and write to output file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BS 12

int main (const int argc, const char** argv)
{
  if(argc != 3)
    exit(-1);

  unsigned char buffer[BS];
  FILE * f1, * f2;
  f1 = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  f2 = fopen(argv[2], "w");

  fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_END);

  long i = 0, j = 0;
  long f1_len = ftell(f1);
  unsigned char tmp;

 // while(i >= 0)
//  {
    for(i = ftell(f1), j = 0; i >= 0 && j <= BS - 1; i--, j++)
    {
      fseek(f1, i, SEEK_SET);
      tmp = fgetc(f1);

      if(i == f1_len || tmp == (unsigned char)0x03)
        continue;
      else
        buffer[j] = tmp;
    }
    if(j == BS - 1)
      fwrite(buffer, BS, 1, f2);
    else
      fwrite(buffer, j, 1, f2);

    fflush(f2);
 // }

  fclose(f1);
  fclose(f2);

    return 0;
}
```

testfile:

```
$ xxd testfile
0000000: 6162 6364 6566 670a                      abcdefg.
```

test:

```
$ gcc test.c -o test
$ test testfile testfile2
$ xxd testfile2
0000000: 030a 6766 6564 6362 61                   ..gfedcba
```

Why is there a '0x03'? I already wrote `tmp == (unsigned char)0x03` to get rid of that char, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned 0x03 is uninitialized memory. Furthermore, you have another problem: fseek(f1,ftell(f1),SEEK_SET) moves the file position to the end. The next fgetc() will return EOF. Therefore, your loop should look like this:

for(i = **ftell(f1)-1**, j = 0; i >= 0 && j <= BS - 1; i--, j++) {....}

Answer (score 2):

When you use `continue`, the character 0x03 is skipped, but the `j++` still gets executed, so the buffer moves forward.

This means that the `0x03` is actually uninitialized memory.

Just move the `j++` at the end of your loop instead of inside the loop declaration.

---

Side node: reading your code I get the impression that it could be improved in many ways. Maybe you should ask about it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ when the bug is fixed.